# one day less when converting milliseconds to date in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've encountered this very interesting issue when converting timestamp to date in sqlite query.

What am doing is saving the time in a database table say 'dummytable' which I obtained using `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeMillis()/1000;`

n while retrieving all I'm doing is `Select date(stored_date_in_millis,'unixepoch');` but the date returned here is the previous date and not the actual date which was converted to milliseconds.

For instance:- I've passed the timestamp = 1391452200 which translates to 4th feb, 2014.
when querying `select date(1391452200,'unixepoch');` i'm getting 2014-02-03.

Comment: why do you divide per 1000?

Comment: to convert milliseconds to seconds as `date` method of sqlite takes timestamp in seconds and NOT milliseconds

Comment: [This site](http://www.epochconverter.com/) given "1391452200" returns 3rd feb, 2014.  Is this a time zone issue perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timezone issue.. Solved it by using `date(time_in_millis, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');`